# Scrape data from webpage under 'popup' box

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from a website. The problem is the data is only visible when the mouse pointer is hovering over it...
On the following page, I would like to extract the historical congestion levels (right bottom, when mouse on e.g. 2011)
https://www.tomtom.com/en_gb/trafficindex/city/mexico-city

I'm somewhat familiar with beautiful soup. Any ideas on how to tackle this, if possible after all...

Many thanks and sorry for the high level question, but I wanted to check feasibility before diving into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach here is to request the json file (`/en_gb/trafficindex/data.json`) directly.
The file contains a list of 390 items, one for each city. You could create a dictionary from this list with 'cityCode' as keys and 'congestionHistory' as values, and access the data by city code.

An example with `requests`:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.tomtom.com/en_gb/trafficindex/data.json"
r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()
congestion_data = {
    i['cityTraffic']['cityCode']: i['cityTraffic']['congestionHistory'] 
    for i in data
}

print(congestion_data['MEX'])
```

> [{'year': 2010, 'congestion': 57}, {'year': 2011, 'congestion': 59}, ...

And saving it as a csv file:

```
import csv

with open('my_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as f: 
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(['city_code', 'congestion_history'])
    for k,v in congestion_data.items():
        w.writerow((k, ', '.join('{1}:{0}'.format(*i.values()) for i in v)))
```

Comment: Many thanks Adam, works great! :)

I was wondering, in the end my goal is to have this data for all the cities. Would this be possible with the json file?

Comment: Super, there is a lot of interesting data in the JSON indeed!

Just to understand, what type of data is 'congestion_data'? (is it a list?)
Is it possible to write to Excel with Openpyxl?

Comment: `congestion_data` is a dict that contains lists of dicts.. it's complicated. I don't have any experience with openpyxl, so i can't help with that, but i posted a csv example. However the data is inconsistent (for example 'MEX' has 7 items but 'BAN' has only 2) so i just formated it in a string.

Comment: One more question. How did you figured out how to access the JSON file? Is it always just adding JSON to the link?

Comment: I should have mentioned that in my answer, sorry. When scraping data from websites always use Inspact. In this case i found the link by inspecting the network traffic (and filter by XHR) when loading the page.

Comment: Thanks Adam! It's not 100% clear yet to me, if okay for you we can take this up in private chat & I will delete this comment then?

Comment: I've created a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161064/scrape-data-from-webpage-under-popup-box)